# How do I sanitize the str_replace function in javascript variables

Tags: validation, sanitization, datepicker

I have the following code in the javascript which outputs the date(s). With backslash for that, I'm replacing those strings with the `str_replace` to remove backslash, but I can't sanitize that using any escaping function like `esc_js`.

**Stored Days Array**

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string '4/7/2018' (length=8)
  1 => string '11/18/2017'(length=10)
```

**The code**

```
var disabledDays = <?php echo str_replace( '\\/', '/', wp_json_encode( $iva_disable_days ) ); ?>;
```

**Tried Code which is not working**

```
var disabledDays = <?php echo esc_js( str_replace( '\\/', '/', wp_json_encode( $iva_disable_days ) ) ); ?>;
```

Result Output

```
var disabledDays = [&quot;4/7/2018&quot;,&quot;11/18/2017&quot;];
```

How do I sanitize the above section in **The Code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`esc_js()` is intended for escaping data for use within an HTML attribute.

If you want to escape data for use within an inline script, `wp_json_encode()` should be sufficient.

For example:

```
var disabledDays = <?php echo wp_json_encode( $iva_disable_days ); ?>;
```

This outputs:

```
var disabledDays = ["4\/7\/2018","11\/18\/2017"];
```

If you check the variable in your dev tools console, you will see that it is being parsed correctly:

[image]

However - if you absolutely do not want escaped slashes (not recommended), the second param to `wp_json_encode()` is a bitmask of options:

```
var disabledDays = <?php echo wp_json_encode( $iva_disable_days, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ); ?>;
```

This outputs:

```
var disabledDays = ["4/7/2018","11/18/2017"];
```

For a list of available options, check the [PHP `json_encode()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Removed the `str_replace` and worked with the encoding by the supplied options `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`